# How do I append an image to a src within a div?

Tags: jquery, html, image, append, src

I've been creating a "shopping site". I have code that allows me to add info from a javascript object to html. Everything is being added except the image, which it returns as text. Here is my code:

```
    <div id= "book1">
    <div id= "twilight" class= "book product">
        <div class= "name"> </div>
        <div class= "catagory"></div>
        <div class= "price"></div>
        <div class= "description"></div>
        <div class= "picture" src= ""></div>
        <div class= "sellingPoints"></div>
    </div> 

    <script>
       var book1 = {
          name: "Twilight",
          catagory: ["Book", "Teen Romance", "Teen Paranormal"],
          description: "Girl meets boy. Boy turns out to be vampire. Girl falls       
          in love with boy. Boy struggles with her love. A-mazing.",
          pictureURL: "image URL",
          price: 15.99,
          sellingPoints:["Forbidden Love", "Love Triangle"]
       }



       $('#book1 .name').text(book1.name);
       $('#book1 .catagory').text(book1.catagory);
       $('#book1 .description').text(book1.description);
       $('#book1 .picture').text(book1.pictureURL);
       $('#book1 .price').text(book1.price);
       $('#book1 .sellingPoints').text(book1.sellingPoint);
    </script>
```

This is roughly what I have (with everything in their respective  and  tags. I didn't include them here). The text is placed where it is suppose to be, but I have no idea how to go about getting the image url to be placed in the src so it shows up as the actual image and not just as a txt url.

Is there a way to do this so it lands within the src? Or is there another way?

Comment: I'd rather not assume you have a typo in your code; you do realize you can format code with 4 spaces, and you don't need to use inline-formatting(`), right?  It may throw some people off if you don't fix it(I can fix it for you or someone else can of course).

Comment: You need to also use the `<img>` tag instead of a `<div>` tag. Change `<div class= "picture" src= ""></div>` to `<img class="picture" src=""></img>`. Thom-x's answer below seems right.

Comment: Oh, this was my first question on stackoverflow. I am still getting use to the formatting, and will probably mess up for a while as I try and figure out formatting for questions. Thanks for editing Thom-X!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like that :

```js
       var book1 = {
          name: "Twilight",
          catagory: ["Book", "Teen Romance", "Teen Paranormal"],
          description: "Girl meets boy. Boy turns out to be vampire. Girl falls in love with boy. Boy struggles with her love. A-mazing.",
          pictureURL: "http://lorempixel.com/400/200",
          price: 15.99,
          sellingPoints:["Forbidden Love", "Love Triangle"]
       }



       $('#book1 .name').text(book1.name);
       $('#book1 .catagory').text(book1.catagory);
       $('#book1 .description').text(book1.description);
       $('#book1 .picture').attr("src",book1.pictureURL);
       $('#book1 .price').text(book1.price);
       $('#book1 .sellingPoints').text(book1.sellingPoint);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id= "book1">
    <div id= "twilight" class= "book product">
        <div class= "name"> </div>
        <div class= "catagory"></div>
        <div class= "price"></div>
        <div class= "description"></div>
        <img class= "picture" src="" alt="">
        <div class= "sellingPoints"></div>
    </div>
```

Use `.attr("src",book1.pictureURL)` to change the `src` attribute of the image.

Comment: So in my case, where I want the image to show up, I would not put it in a div but rather in an <img>? That makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, you need to use <img> to display an image http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_img.asp.

Comment: Oh I knew that, was just thinking that <img> could be used similar to other div identifiers such as class, id, align.

Answer (score 1):

Use **.attr()** [here](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

In your javascript function select the element whos **src** tag you want changed then set the src tag:

```
$('.picture').attr('src', book1.pictureURL)
```

Comment: are you saying something like
    $('#book1 .picture').attr('src', book2.pictureURL)

Comment: Ah, I figured out what you were saying. Thanks code!

Answer (score 1):

You should set the src, not the text for picture as follows:

```
$('#book1 .picture').attr('src', book1.pictureURL);
```

Comment: I realize why putting .text was giving me text! duh. Thanks Alp

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
$('#book1 .picture').html('<img src="'+book1.pictureURL+'" />');
```

Comment: Like the user "code" mentioned attr is better here, I only now saw your src attr in the div.

Comment: This worked thanks! I am new and I forgot you could add html in the () along with where you are pulling information from.

Answer (score 0):

Very easy.

You can't have an image on the div but you need an [html image element](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_img.asp) within the div. First, include an [image](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_img.asp) within the picture `div`:

`<div><img class= "picture" src=""/></div>`

then, you will be able to change the `src` of the image. I changed the `class` of the image to `"picture"` instead of the `div` so you will be able to directly select the image and change the `src` like this:

`$('#book1 .picture').attr('src', book1.pictureURL);`

Comment: Thanks! This makes perfect sense, cannot have image in a div but I can have an image tag within a div tag. So helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Possibly use [append](http://api.jquery.com/append/):

```
$(".picture").append("<img src='<<url>>'/>");
```

Answer (score -1):

Did you try using html() method instead of text() while trying to append image to the DOM element. Hope that works.